# django - another application accessing temporary uploaded file

Tags: python, django, logparser

**My Objective**: I am trying to upload event log file (.evtx), convert it in the backend using LogParser tool into csv, and visualize the data afterward. The Logparser tool will be run by command line using os.system(cmdline_string). Basically I am trying to parse the uploaded file without saving the temporary uploaded file to the file system.

**My Problem**: I am parsing the event log using Log Parser's command line. I cannot access the temporary uploaded file in appdata\local\temp using log parser's command line.

**Code**:

*uploadfile.html*

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def uploadfile():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'myfile' in request.FILES:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']

    filename, fileext = os.path.splitext(myfile.name)

    if fileext == '.evtx':
        cmdstring = "logparser " + \
                    "\"SELECT * INTO " + "output.csv" + \
                    " FROM " + myfile.temporary_file_path() + "\" " + \
                    "-i:EVT -o:CSV"
        os.system(cmdstring)
        # This will output error: 
        # Cannot open <from-entity>: Error opening event log /path/to/uploadedfiles: 
        # The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I am guessing that probably the temporary file is being accessed by django thus logparser cannot access the file. When I tried to save the file into filesystem, logparser is able to access and parse the file. When I simply access and parse any event log data in AppData\Local\Temp directory, it is also manage to do it.

How to let another application access temp uploaded file in django?

**My Environment**: Windows 10, Python 3.6.1. Django 1.11.4, Log Parser 2.2

Comment: In your view uploadfile you are not saving it in filesystem explicitly. It will be in memory by default unless it a large file. If you want to access this file make sure it exists in the filesystem or you may have to save it before trying to do so.

Comment: Why don't you just save the file to disk explicitely before passing it to the parser ?

Comment: I can save the file, parse it, and delete the original file afterward but I am looking shorter ways than that where by we dont need to explicitly save the file. My file is >2.5MB so django will keep it in file system as TemporaryUploadedFile class instead of InMemoryUploadedFile class.